# Download XML Data In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularjs. My requirement is I have a Button in UI, whenever user click on that button It get data from database and convert into XML. And Download the XML data into local system. Till Now I am able to get data from database and I have converted that data in XML using JAXB(java). Now I want to download same data please someone suggest me how to download. thank you

this is what I have done-

In UI Form

```
<input type="button" class="btn green" ng-click="exportXml()" value="Export" />
<a ng-href="{{ fileUrl }}" download="file.txt" id="export">download</a>
```

JS function

```
$scope.exportXml = function() {
     var response = $http.get('/demo/rest/getData');
     response.success(function(data){
         blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
         url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
         $scope.fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
         alert($scope.fileUrl);
         document.getElementById('export').click();
     });
     response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         alert("Error in Fetching Data");
     });
 };
```

Comment: please share your code what you have done yet...

Comment: thnx for response, I have update my question. please check